# Python unicode encoding for regular expression

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I have files with lines with unicode encodings like `D\u00f3nde est\u00e1s`.
I would like to check each word if it contains only characters from the set locale.

This code does not completely work. The string seems to be correctly transformed to `Dónde estás` and wordmatch matches each word, but it does not consider the locale setting. E.g. if I set the locale to en_US it still matches both words even though they contain `ó` and `á` characters.

Using re.LOCALE instead of re.UNICODE also does not seem to work, and both words no longer match the wordmatch regular expression.

```
import re
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'en_ES')
wordmatch=re.compile(r'^\w*$',re.UNICODE)

line="D\u00f3nde est\u00e1s"
line=line.decode('unicode_escape')

for word in line.split():
    if wordmatch.match(word):
        print "Matched "+word
    else:
        print "No match "+word
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the locale doesn't directly mean changing the encoding, and the encoding for `en_US` is not forcibly `ascii`. On my system, for example it is `iso-8859-1`, an encoding where `ó` and `á` are valid. This could explain why `re.LOCALE` doesn't complain about these characters.

To manipulate encodings, I would rather use the `encode` function than regular expressions:

```py
line="D\u00f3nde est\u00e1s"
line=line.decode('unicode_escape')

# get current encoding, or set to "ascii" if you want to be more restrictive
pref_encoding = locale.getpreferedencoding()

for word in line.split():
    try:
        w = word.encode(pref_encoding)
    except UnicodeEncodeError as e:
        print "This word contains unacceptable characters: ", word
        break
```